# Transform an exponential equation within another exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function, transformation

My question comes from a statistical problem I am bumping into but I think it is more a math question than a stats question, therefore I post it here.

Anyway, I have a Structural Equation Model that includes several links. However, some of the links are non-linear. I tried a whole bunch of stuff with polynomials but that is just not working. I have now created several non-linear least square regression models that fit the non-linearity quite good. I now want to use these exponential equations from these models to transform my data so it become linear after which I want to use it in my linear Structural Equation Model.

So there is variable $S$ which is dependent on variable $G$ which is dependent on variable $T$. $S$ and $G$ are non-linear related and $G$ and $T$ are non-linear related too.

Variable $S$ is related to $G$ in the following way:

$sqrt(S) = a(1+sqrt(G))^{-b}$

Variable $G$ is related to $T$ in the following way:

$sqrt(G) = c(1+T)^{-d}+e$

I need to transform $S$ in a way that it becomes linear with $G$, using these equations. However, $G$ needs to be transformed first so $S$ is actually a function of the transformed $G$. Hence, both equations need to be used to transform $S$ because:

$sqrt(S) = a(1+sqrt((c(1+T)^{-d}+e)))^{-b}$

I need to transform both the $G$ and $S$ variable. The problem is that I have tried a few things, but I am just not confident that I am doing it right. Please help!

Comment: Is the $e$ in the exponent? That is, is $G=c(1+T)^{-d+e}$ or $G=c(1+T)^{-d}+e$?

Comment: @Dave no e is not part of the exponent. It should be like the last one in your comment. thanks

Comment: @Dave Also, I forgot to mention that the variables S and G are square root transformed (due to variance issues).